# if field X in any row has value Y then ignore else group results by GROUP BY in mysql without subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have two tables:

users

```
id |  admin_id   | name
 -----------------------
  1 |    10       | a
  2 |    10       | b
  3 |    15       | c
  4 |    10       | d
  5 |    10       | e
  6 |    10       | f
```

status

```
 id |  user_id    | status
 -----------------------
  1 |     2       | error
  2 |     2       | success
  3 |     2       | error
  4 |     4       | success
  5 |     6       | error
```

now I am trying to get all users of **admin_id 10** who don't have any entry in table **status** and the users which don't have any entry with **status success** in status table by using group by clause.
My expected results are:

Result:

```
 id |  admin_id   | name  |  status
 ------------------------------------
  1 |     10      |   a   |  null
  5 |     10      |   e   |  null
  6 |     10      |   f   |  error
```

So as per the expected results the query should ignore the user_id 2,4 because these two have success status in status table. Right now I am trying to make the query like this:

```
SELECT
    users.*,
    status.status
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    status ON users.id = status.user_id
WHERE
    users.admin_id = 10 AND status.status != "success"
GROUP BY
    users.id
```

It can be done by sub-query but my requirement is to do it with single query and without using sub-query.

Is there a way to do this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should move the success condition away from the `where` clause into the `join ... on` clause:

```
SELECT
    users.*,
    status.status
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    status ON users.id = status.user_id AND status.status != "success"
WHERE
    users.admin_id = 10 
GROUP BY
    users.id
```

A side note unrelated to your question: it is non-standard to SQL to specify columns in your `select` clause which are neither grouped by, nor functionally dependent on a grouped by expression, nor aggregated.

So better is to aggregate the status in some way (choose what best suits your needs: `min`, `max`, ...):

```
SELECT
    users.*,
    min(status.status) as status
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    status ON users.id = status.user_id AND status.status != "success"
WHERE
    users.admin_id = 10 
GROUP BY
    users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next query. We first group by the users columns you are using on the SELECT clause, then we use HAVING clause for discard those groups whose count of **status="success"** is greater than zero.

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    users.admin_id,
    users.name,
    MAX(status.status)
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    status ON status.user_id = users.id
WHERE
    users.admin_id = 10
GROUP BY
    users.id, users.admin_id, users.name
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN status.status = "success" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```